# iOS App Crashes on start ˜(relative path not allowed in hardened program), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS' (not a file)˜

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

So I've been scratching my head over a week on this by now, ever since I've updated my iOS to 17, Xcode to 15.2 and MacOS on my machine, every app I compile and deploy crashes on open (using Delphi 11 Alexandria Fire Monkey), there is a community fix for it adding line inside one of the FMX libraries.

However one specific app that fix doesn't work, it crashes before I can get any custom log messages, what I get from the ˜Recent Logs in Xcode is as it follows

```
"termination": {
"code": 1,
"flags": 518,
"namespace": "DYLD",
"indicator": "Library missing",
"details": [
"(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"
],
"reasons": [
"Library not loaded:",
"Referenced from: <9807A387-C221-3164-ABE4-084FAF74E32D> /Volumes/VOLUME/*/EasyConnect.app/EasyConnect",
"Reason: tried: '' (relative path not allowed in hardened program), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS' (not a file), '' (relative path not allowed in hardened program)"
]
```

Full log - https://pastebin.com/mkdaJVsf

It seems like it's trying to look for a Lib or Framework at a file path that doesn't exist, the folder "Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/Framework" does exist in the iOS SDK on my Windows machine linked to Delphi, inside it I have ˜JavaScriptCore.Framework˜, ˜SafariServices.Framework˜ and ˜WebKit.Framework˜, I've put all 3 as Library Paths in my iOS SDK settings and Updated Local File Cache but still doesn't work.

I'm trying to run my app in an iPad

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: The project itself is way too big to just put any code, the closet I could add would be the IPA file?